# Maintain jQuery onChange After a Replacewith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that grabs the first select on the page and clones it so that I can reset it later on if needed.

```
mySelect = jQuery('select').get(0);
origSelect = jQuery(mySelect).clone();

jQuery(mySelect).change(function(){
   //some code
}
```

When I fire the code to reset the select with:

```
jQuery(mySelect).replaceWith(origSelect);
```

The onChange function stops working.  I've determined that it's because it is now referred to as origSelect and responds to onChanges for that name.  Do I have any options here for replacing the content of mySelect with the content of origSelect without changing the name it's referred to by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a parameter true to the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

```
origSelect = jQuery(mySelect).clone(true); //This will clone the select with data and events
```

or replace the innerHTMl of origSelect with that of mySelect.

```
jQuery(origSelect).html(jQuery(mySelect).html());
```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know that you could do this with just `.clone(true)`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(mySelect).live('change', ...)` instead of `$(mySelect).change(...)`.